# C# Stacking panels vs new form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, panel

Still quite new to programming and was wondering whether stacking panels on top of each other and just swapping out which ones are visible, or opening a new form would be most efficient. Or is it perhaps a combination of the 2?

The program i am doing at the moment will have quite a lot of different layouts that i will need to be able to go back and forth between.

Edit: It will be close to a survey where the user has to answer some questions and then click a button to go on to the next page.

Comment: Take a look a the tab container

Comment: You can actually make your form large enough to hold the panels where they are not stacked on top of each other and simply set the position of the visible panel at the time it goes visible. I'd suggest not stacking them in the designer as it makes it very hard to layout/make sense of it all.

Comment: @Flydog57 I did look briefly at tab container but thought it meant the user would then manually swap the tabs as they used the program and i want that to be bound to buttons instead. Should probably have said it will be somewhat like a survey with some pages each with new questions to answer for the user.

Comment: @Mikael Thanks, that will help a lot, atm i have to send to back every time i want to edit another panel.

Comment: Tabs still work in that scenario (I'm guessing it's a guided wizard thing). You pop up one tab. When everything is good, you pop up another (perhaps (perhaps not) disabling the first). Repeat as necessary. It allows the user to go back and look at previous pages

Comment: @Flydog57 Ahh i see, thank you! I will take a closer look at it then.